# Why would ws_PartLog.Range("A7:DM1007").ClearContents work on one computer and not another?

Tags: excel, vba

In the below VBA code snippet, when the function block `clear()` is called I receive an undefined error on this line `ws_PartLog.Range("A7:DM1007").ClearContents`

This only happens when this Excel file is used on a particular computer. The Excel version is 2016. It does work fine on another 2016 install as well a 360 install.

What could cause this to work on one computer and not another?

```
'Public Vars for this workbook
Public wb_Kepware As Workbook     'orig wbBook1
Public wb_PartLog As Workbook     'orig wbBook2
Public ws_Kepware As Worksheet    'orig wsSheet1
Public ws_PartLog As Worksheet    'orig wsSheet2


Public Sub SvLog() 'Save filename as value of A1 plus the current date

    ws_PartLog.Activate
    
    Dim newFile As String, fName As String, folder As String
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    
    fName = ws_Kepware.Range("D44").Text  ' D44 = now() = "41923151917"
    
    newFile = fName
    
     ' Change directory to suit
    folder = ws_Kepware.Range("D40").Value   ' D40 = "C:\DATA_LOGGER\WL75_Logs"
    'MsgBox (folder)
    ChDrive Left(folder, 1)
    ChDir folder 
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=newFile
    
    Set wb_PartLog = GetWorkbook(wb_Kepware.Worksheets("Kepware").Range("D40").Value + "\" + fName + ".xlsm")
    
    Set ws_PartLog = wb_PartLog.Worksheets("Log")
    
    ws_Kepware.Range("J44").Value = fName
    
    Call clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    
    ws_Kepware.Activate    
End Sub

Public Sub clear()

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'MsgBox (ws_PartLog.Name)
    ws_PartLog.Activate
    ws_PartLog.Range("A7:DM1007").ClearContents   '<< ws_PartLog undefined
    ws_PartLog.Range("A7:DM1007").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    ws_PartLog.Range("A7").Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Public Function GetWorkbook(ByVal sFullName As String) As Workbook

    Dim sFile As String
    Dim wbReturn As Workbook
    
    sFile = Dir(sFullName)
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set wbReturn = Workbooks(sFile)
        
        If wbReturn Is Nothing Then
            Set wbReturn = Workbooks.Open(sFullName)
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set GetWorkbook = wbReturn
    
End Function
```

I've tried defining the worksheet and workbook in the function with no resolve.

```
Public Sub clear()

    Set wb_PartLog = GetWorkbook(Worksheets("Kepware").Range("D40").Value + "\" + Worksheets("Kepware").Range("J44").Text + ".xlsm")  'GetWorkbook will open workbook if not already open.
    Set ws_PartLog = wb_PartLog.Worksheets("Log")

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'MsgBox (ws_PartLog.Name)
    ws_PartLog.Activate
    ws_PartLog.Range("A7:DM1007").ClearContents
    ws_PartLog.Range("A7:DM1007").Interior.ColorIndex = 0    
    ws_PartLog.Range("A7").Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't think to try and remove `On Error Resume Next` .  It's not in the same function I'm having an issue with. I can give that a try and see what the results are.

Comment: The title and the body mention different lines on which the error happens, and do not mention the actual error message.

Comment: Thanks Gserg, I didn't catch that when I copied the code to the body. I had tried both .Value = "" and .ClearContents. Both give an undefined error for ws_PartLog I Just updated the title to match the body.

Comment: What is an undefined error?

Comment: @GSerg I don't have access to this machine at this moment to get the exact error. The error is stating that the worksheet ws_PartLog is undefined.

Comment: what is `wb_Kepware` ?

Comment: It's a reference to another workbook not used in this part of the code.

Comment: you are using it in `Set wb_PartLog = GetWorkbook(wb_Kepware.Worksheets("Kepware").Range("D40").Value + "\" + fName + ".xlsm")` which in turn uses `Set ws_PartLog = wb_PartLog.Worksheets("Log")` and since it is public it will reflect in the other sub

Comment: I strongly assume that on the "other" computer the workbook file is not present or not accessible. As you use `On Error Resume Next`, your function `GetWorkbook` will not throw an error and return `Nothing`.